# "Wild" surge of solar panel current in the mppt-controller model

Tags: power-supply, voltage, measurement, current-source, modeling

I ask the help of electrical engineers.
I am developing a model of an MPPT-controller, the model has not yet been completed (only DC-DC, the load and the panel itself are connected). I do it in simulink.

[image]

I am very worried about some extremely wild jump in solar panel current to no-load current level.

[image]

*How can this jump be explained and how can it be eliminated?*

The circuit parameters are as follows:

R1=1 Ohm;
C1=2e-3 F;
L=0.1 H;
R=150 Ohm;

I would be glad and grateful for advice and help.

Comment: Please elaborate on why you say 'no load', in the diagram above, it appears that you have a filter and a load connected to the filter. Also, if you want to adequately model a physical MPPT control loop, usually a mosfet that switches will be necessary to regulate the voltage.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Well, why, I didn't seem to write that there is no load, it is there (Resistor R). Said "the model has not yet been completed (only DC-DC, the load and the panel itself are connected)" That is, it says that the panel, load and filter are connected. As for the transistor: why MOS and not IGBT?

Comment: @VoltageSpike the model is not finished because mppt control is not connected yet. I am currently working on it. I would like to explain the surge in solar panel current.