# Alternative MOS and IGBT for MPPT controllers

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, solar-cell, control-system

Are there alternatives to MOS and IGBT-transistors for MPPT-controllers?

Let's say we are considering a solar panel as a power source.

This power supply has an optimal state, because such a ratio of current and voltage, which allows you to give maximum power.

The devices and algorithms for achieving this state are known to everyone (*I’m just trying to study this issue, though in theory*). These are *DC-DC, Boost converters* based on a MOS or IGBT-transistor, controlled through PWM by selecting the duty cycle.

What about similar devices that work without PWM?
Are there such ones that allow you to smoothly select the parameters of the chain to achieve the optimal state without PWM?

**Edit:**

Dear Colleagues!
decided to include small additions to the question.

*New Scheme:*
[image]

Old scheme:
["Wild" surge of solar panel current in the mppt-controller model](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574611/wild-surge-of-solar-panel-current-in-the-mppt-controller-model)

After independent work, I decided to include an H-bridge in the circuit. This has improved the quality of power (and therefore voltage and current).

[image]

In this case, the system works with PWM, and the inverse branch of the converter is blocked.

In this case, the system includes a sinusoidal extremum seeking, instead of perturbation and observation.

**EDIT№2:**

I post the previous circuit and graphs of optimal power for comparison. In such a circuit, the power quality is much worse.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT№3:**

General structure of MPPT controller
[image]

Comment: This comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable in comments, so it has been moved to chat (link below). As this bulk moving of comments can only be done once, any further comments discussing the question might be removed without notice. **Keep it in the chat, please!** If someone gets enough information in the chat to post an answer, then please do that as normal. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127361/discussion-on-question-by-dtn-alternative-mos-and-igbt-for-mppt-controllers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the point about MOS or IGBT transistors - PWM can be achieved with any device that can handle the correct voltage/current and can switch between fully on and fully off. It happens that MOS and IGBT devices are good for this purpose in practice.

Regarding PWM - the alternative to PWM is linear regulation, which involves operating a transistor in a partially-on state (i.e. saturation in a MOSFET, where drain current is controlled by gate voltage). However, this leads to a voltage drop across the switching element, and thus wastes tons of energy and creates heat, much like a linear regulator. For solar power, your efficiency drops, and you now need to reject heat as well, so you pay the penalty of having heatsinks, and perhaps active fans.

PWM is good for this kind of application because it draws energy from the supply with only modest conduction losses (on-resistance loss during the on-time, leakage during the off-time, and linear losses during a very brief period as the state is switching). All of the filtering is done using reactive elements (e.g. input and output capacitors, inductor) and hence does not dissipate lots of energy (of course, parasitic resistance leads to dissipation). Barring some new linear phenomena such as [superconducting DC transformers](https://cds.cern.ch/record/794618/files/project-note-355.pdf), you won't be able to achieve the same without modulating your transistors between fully on and fully off - whether it's pulse width modulation, modulating the frequency of fixed-length pulses, or something else that only has fully-on and fully-off states.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, you quite rightly understood my question - I am looking for linear algorithms and devices that allow you me reach the optimal state continuously. At the same time, I agree that heating and losses are more relevant than ever for the case of using the panel as a power source. For general development and understanding, however, I would like to learn more about linear devices and algorithms and simulate their continuous operation in Simulink. Could you enlighten me about them?

Comment: see my edit, please

Comment: @dtn I'm not sure where your level of knowledge currently falls, but you should just be able to set up linear devices as part of a control loop, as long as they are either beefy enough to handle the dissipation, or are idealized simulation models that don't have thermal considerations. The process of designing the controls would use similar skills to transistor circuits in general. I don't know Simulink well enough to comment on your design, but I agree with the chat that you should decouple the PWM power stage from the control loop altogether (by making PWM faster than control loop dynamics)

Comment: good point about the pwm frequency. I increased it and the quality of transients improved. but nevertheless, in the h-bridge circuit, everything is much better. how to explain this - I do not know yet.

Comment: @dtn An H-bridge driven by a PWM waveform is still a PWM-modulated switching device. It might have better electrical behavior, but to me, the Simulink models are unfamiliar and opaque so I cannot make an informed statement at the electronic device design level.

Comment: yes, in an amicable way, I need to design a control system together with a converter, but so far I am not able to do this, so I will have to deal with ready-made